# Google Ads Conversions for iOS issue

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

I have set it up adsupport, adservices, iad [frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oezDq.png) and more, but still no conversions on Google Ads as a conversion.

Google ads takes first_open but no subscription_convert or renew...

Any idea?

I have tried it with different ad accounts but no difference.

Comment: I can see conversions on firebase/analytics, but not added to google ads, 

I had the same issue for different app but its fixed when I add adsupport framework, but not this time. Any advice or help are welcome.